# Thread is printing two times at same loop

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, flask, debian

Inside of each loop the thread is printing two times. In this case, it prints two times to each 3 seconds. I want that it prints only one time.

on Flask:

```
from flask import Flask
import threading
from time import sleep


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
  return 'ok'

def func():
  count = 1
  while True:
    print(count)
    count += 1
    sleep(3)

t = threading.Thread(target=func)
t.setDaemon(True)
t.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug=True)
```

output:

```
1
1
2
2
3
3
...
```

expected output:

```
1
2
3
...
```

Comment: do you get the 0.99 seconds of delay even between the duplicate numbers?

Comment: can you edit your post to show the *entire* code if it is not way too big?

Comment: Doens't matter the time, it prints two times. In this case it prints two times to each 0.99 seconds. If I change to 5 seconds for example, it'll to print two times to each 5 seconds.

About the code, it's too big because I am running it in Flask system.

Comment: I edited the post, now you can to see the thread in Flask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the why.

When run modules like threading and apscheduler in Flask with debug mode: on ...
it happens.